# Subtract a value from a column in fuel php query builder

Tags: php, mysql, fuelphp

I tried to subtract a numerical value from one column in FuelPHP query builder.

Its like this.

```
update item set price = price - 1000;
```

And I wrote codes like this:

```
$query = DB::update('item')->set(array('price'=>'price'-1000));
```

However, this doesn't subtract 1000 from price and this result is always "price:-1000".

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use/chain `->value()` in the query builder and use `DB::expr()` on top of that.

Example:

```
$value = 1000;
$query = DB::update('item')
->where('product_id', 999)
->value('price', DB::expr('price - ' . $value)) // i prefer using this, much more straightforward
->execute(); // DONT FORGET TO EXECUTE!
```

Or using `->set()` if you decide to really use multiple fields:

```
->set(array(
    'price' => DB::expr('price - ' . $value)
))
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I didn't know this method "->value". It helps. And thank you for correcting my poor English.

Comment: @user3119018 i can't remember what i corrected in the wordings of the question as i am bad at english too lol , but im glad this answer helped